# pentest-verify checklist after cheked

Tags: verify, penetration-testing

After pentesting and checking the check-list, how can I reassure my client that these checks are done and vulnerabilities patched? (of course for something like sqli, showing is obvious)
But I mean somewhere to verify or something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For test checks that are done you can provide different reports generated by tools or manual testing (depending on vulnerability type) for those specific checks.

While for patched vulnerabilities, you will need to re-test the platform again and provide the changed reports either generated from tools or manual testing that will show different output by indicating the vulnerability is no longer present. 
For further re-assurance you can also add the vulnerability exploitation reproducing steps on the report. So if the client wants to test it themselves they can do it (and get assured that it was fixed).

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe all methodologies used like OSSTMM, OWASP, NIST. Is very important too talk about the perimeter tested (web like forms, api, frameworks, network protocols,etc).

However, you can create a topic every step tested using Top10Owasp:

- Broken Authentication
- Sensitive data exposure
- XML External Entities (XXE)
- Broken Access control
- Security misconfigurations
- Cross Site Scripting (XSS)
- Insecure Deserialization
- Using Components with known vulnerabilities
- Insufficient logging and monitoring

This way you ensure that your test was compliance.